# Lubuntu 16.04 LTS fresh install fsck freeze

Tags: boot, lubuntu, live-usb

I have just installed lubuntu 16.04 on EEE PC, but I am unable to start it because on startup fsck runs and it freezes at:

```
/dev/sda1: clean, 121552/9707520 files, 1258598/38812416 blocks
```

And no other output appears. I tried to run 'try lubuntu' from live usb, but It also failed, because after choosing this option all I can see is black screen.

Comment: Lubuntu was giving me the identical problem as well, in the end I opted for installing xubuntu minimal using the ubuntu mini iso.

Answer (score 0):

Same for me after I tried to upgrade Lubuntu to 16.04 LTS on a eee-PC 701 equipped with a 32 GB SD card.

I erased the internal SSD with DBAN (about 16 min) then I installed Lubuntu, but it didn't boot, resulting in the same freeze as you.
I tried to install Mint LMDE 2 after another SSD erase: no boot.
Every times I accepted GRUB installation and I used Gparted to define partitions on SSD and SD card. Then I found this: ["Align to MiB or to Cylinder"](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/gparted-partitioning-options-align-to-cylinder-or-to-mib-834366/) and I changed the settings in Gparted to "Align to cylinder".

After a third SSD erase, I installed antiX (small Debian fork distro) and all is fine now.

Hope this help
P

Answer (score 0):

Lubuntu 16.04 blank boot screen, flashing cursor - Intel 9xx graphics
A few computers equiped with Intel 9xx series graphics hardware fail to boot Lubuntu 16.04. The software will install but the system hangs during boot with only a flashing cursor visible on screen. This is caused by missing Intel graphics drivers.

The solution is to hold 'right shift' key during boot to access the Grub menu, then press 'e' key to edit the the commands. Locate the words 'quiet splash' on screen, then use arrow keys to navigate and add the word 'nomodeset' just after 'quiet splash'. This will allow the system to boot to a low resolution desktop.

Finally, use the included Synaptic Package Manager to install 'xserver-xorg-video-intel' and 'xserver-xorg-video-intel-dbg' and restart.

Answer (score 0):

I just use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to get to a login prompt on a VT, log in and then run `startx` (I have Xfce installed on a 701 with 16.04 vanilla Ubuntu however, via the mini iso just on the 4GB SSD).